# Dropbox URL gives access to file content

Tags: security, dropbox, privacy

I am very surprised that I linked on a Dropbox URL stored in my web browser's history and, without being logged in, I could see the content of the file.

I have created a new file to test it and, just with the URL that is accessed by the web browser, anyone can see this file which theoretically has never been shared with anyone: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/eprarh4pibp39mrrgsqw6/Document.docx?dl=0&new=1&rlkey=ghlowj8k67bf5vljtr6jkv42b

I know that you will say that the URL is "secret", but URLs can be seen:

- By other users even if I have logged out from Dropbox.
- The ISP.
- Anyone who guesses a URL (probably this is impossible in practice).

Do you know if this is normal? Isn't it a big security concern?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/107941

Comment: Did you change the share permissions on the file?  This seems more like a Web Applications Stack Exchange question due to the nature of the DropBox service itself rather needing help with the desktop application

Comment: No. It's just a newly created document and I pasted the URL that Firefox showed when I was creating it. I didn't ask Dropbox for a sharing URL or change the sharing permissions at all.

Comment: @user1314836 - So what are the permissions of the file.  Difficult to determine if this is something that was intended or something hat shouldn't have happen.  However, either way, it's probably a question for Drobox not Super User.  Do you make a habit of allowing other users to use the same Windows/Linux user profile?

Comment: I will redirect the question to Dropbox, of course. I couldn't find anything about this on its help or in Google and this security-concerning approach suprised me a lot. I don't have the habit of anyone using my computer, of course, but thinking that just having a URL someone can have access to confidential data is not very relieving, specially because there is no way to know if someone is accessing a file... which hasn't been shared externally. What if some years ago someone guessed the URL of a confidential company file? No way to know who is reading it.

Comment: "What if someone guessed the URL of a confidential company file?" – What if someone guessed the admin's password? Or the private key? The URL you posted is probably harder to guess than most passwords you use. What if someone guessed one of them?

Comment: There is one difference: the URLs I access are not treated as confidential data, so they are stored unprotected in the computer and, I don't know a lot about networks, so I don't know if the URLs can be seen in between my computer and Dropbox (ISP, other users connected to the network or intermediate systems between ISP and Dropbox's servers). A lot of points where if the URL is seen full access is received without knowledge of the user.

Comment: Let's say in another way: I would never trust my bank if I ever show a url like www.mybank.com/my_id/my_bank_password